# loadUserByUsername execute twice using DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using DaoAuthenticationProvider for authenciation but when I submit form loadUserByUsername is called twice by super.authenticate(authentication) intially it throws BadCredentialsException and then next time it login successfully

This process is working fine if I do not use passwordencoder but when I use it loadUserByUsername method is called twice.

Below is my code:

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}

}
```

**Authentication class**

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
@Override
public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    super.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    try {
        System.out.println("inside authenticate");
        Authentication auth = super.authenticate(authentication);
        return auth;
    } catch (BadCredentialsException be) {
        System.out.println("First call comes here ");
        throw be;
    } catch (LockedException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

**MyUserdetailsService class implments UserDetailsService**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

/* below method is called twice if I am using passwordencoder,
initially authentication fails and then again immediately 
on second call authentication succeed */

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.mkyong.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.mkyong.users.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
     MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails (user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(), user.isAccountNonLocked(), user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), user.getEmailId(),authorities);
     return myUserDetails;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

}
```

Can some please help me. I believe there is some change needed in SecurityConfig class but exactly where I am not able to figure out.

Comment: I can take a look but you will have to put it on `github` for me to take a look. There can be lot of things to look at. Your `XML configuration`. Can you carve out a sample project?

Comment: @java_dude. Ok I will put my project in github.

Comment: @java_dude is there any other place where I can directly copy my project and paste. Github finding little difficult

Comment: Take a look at this document for `github` `https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/`. If you still find it difficult put it on your `google drive`. Share with `public` and provide link here and I will access it and put it on `github`.

Comment: @java_dude I have committed file and url for the same is [link](https://github.com/dinespise/Spring-DaoAuthentication)

Comment: You could try to use a debugger to find where first call come from, or to use debug logging on Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after help from java_dude and SergeBallesta I got the resolution for my query.

After a lot of debug I saw that when isPasswordValid method was getting called inside DaoAuthenticationProvider class instead of calling **method 1** it was calling **method 2** from org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder which one is depreciated and on second call it was calling proper isPasswordValid 
method 1.

**Method 1**

```
 public boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt) {
                checkSalt(salt);
                return delegate.matches(rawPass, encPass);
            }
```

**Method 2**

```
 public boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt) {
    String pass1 = encPass + "";

    // Strict delimiters is false because pass2 never persisted anywhere
    // and we want to avoid unnecessary exceptions as a result (the
    // authentication will fail as the encodePassword never allows them)
    String pass2 = mergePasswordAndSalt(rawPass, salt, false);

    if (ignorePasswordCase) {
        // Note: per String javadoc to get correct results for Locale insensitive, use English
        pass1 = pass1.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        pass2 = pass2.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
    return PasswordEncoderUtils.equals(pass1,pass2);
}
```

To work authentication properly just add below code in your SecurityConfig class in addittion to my current code in question.

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
 // LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider is my own class which extends DaoAuthenticationProvider 
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider(); 
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

** and change this method code**

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider())
 .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```