# How to solve unstable behaviour on Spring security getting userdetailsService right

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm tinkering with my Spring Security configuration and I noticed some unpredictable behaviour.

When deploying my Spring boot web and api the custom UserDetailsService is not properly accesible.

I show you the exception log:

```
    2021-09-12 12:49:04.662 ERROR 16344 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2021-09-12 12:49:04.678 ERROR 16344 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(HtmlUtils.java:83) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(HtmlUtils.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.createError(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:372) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.generateLoginPageHtml(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:271) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Debugging at startup I've noticed that dao may be wrongly instantiated:
[image: image that shows some debugg information]

I've configured Spring security as this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CentralSecurityConfiguration {

    //Conexion a datos: Usuarios autorizados
    private static UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(MyUserDetailService uds){
        userDetailsService = uds;
    }

    //Encriptacion
    @Bean
    static PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
//        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance(); // MD5 SHA512 no recomendados.
    }


    private static DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoauthprov =  new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoauthprov.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        daoauthprov.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        return daoauthprov;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http    .csrf().disable()
                    // ANT MATCHERS STUFF
                    ;
        }

    } //FIN CONF API

    
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http    .csrf().disable()
                    // ANT MATCHERS STUFF
                    ;
        }
    } // FIN CONF WEB

    private static class LogoutAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

        // Default handler does an internal forward to a specified URL
        private final AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

        // CompositeLogoutHandler to perform logout activities like normal logout would
        private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler = new CompositeLogoutHandler(
                new CookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"),
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutSuccessEventPublishingLogoutHandler()
        );

        public LogoutAccessDeniedHandler(String errorPage) {
            accessDeniedHandler.setErrorPage(errorPage);
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws ServletException, IOException {
            logoutHandler.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
            accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
        }

    }




}
```

Custom User details service:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UsuarioDAO userRepository;


    public MyUserDetailService(UsuarioDAO userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

       Optional<Usuario> user = userRepository.findByUserName(s);

       user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + s));
       return new MyUserDetails(user.get());

    }
}
```

My current suspicions are:

- I'm not autowiring properly (and I can't figure out why)
- or I lack of a configuration and security is trying to load before the data access is ready so It can't reach.

**UPDATE**: answer to @jms

- The configure global method sets it to the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`
- It's autowired on setter definition: as far as I know it makes the bean used as parameter to be available.

Comment: I am concerned in how you have autowired `userDetailsService`. Also how is `authenticationProvider()` used?

Comment: Answering your question @jms jms

Comment: I've followed advice (on this other question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707680/loaduserbyusername-execute-twice-using-daoauthenticationprovider] about how to @Autowire the different elements. My deploy now gets the authentication right. I hope it survives the sleep time of the server.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Passing beans around using `static` methods and parameters is indeterminate I would say, should be why you had issues in the first place.

Comment: See the [samples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples) which will help while learning the fundamentals. Seek to emulate patterns and code (such as not using `static`) that match the samples. Start small and gradually build from there. It might be easier for us to help if you reduce your sample project to the most minimal example and update your question with that config, as it's not at all clear to me what you're trying to accomplish in the pasted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is Spring has no way to determine that the `authenticationProvider` depends on autowiring the `setUserDetailsService`.

Annotate the `CentralSecurityConfiguration` class with `@Configuration` and add `@ComponentScan` so Spring knows it depends on initializing the services.
You'll need to replace `com.example.services` below with the name of the package containing your `MyUserDetailService`.
Then, because `authenticationProvider` takes a `MyUserDetailService` parameter, it has a dependency that Spring can resolve.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.services")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CentralSecurityConfiguration {

    // ...
    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(MyUserDetailService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoauthprov =  new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoauthprov.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        daoauthprov.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        return daoauthprov;
    }
    
    // ...
```

Comment: Well, recently the project seems more stable in this matter, MyUserDetails and CentralSecurityConfiguration reside inside the same package since this is a Spring Boot project maybe it gets located easier.

Comment: I've used your modification and deployed it, If I find that un-sleeping the application doesn't get it broken the bounty is yours